# Is the DRUPAL_DATABASE_HOST value stored somewhere in the database?

Tags: database, 9

I want to see what the value is for the database host, the value that you enter when installing for the first time.

Is there a way to see and edit this value after installation? Is it stored in a table somewhere?

This is for Drupal 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing named `DRUPAL_DATABASE_HOST` in the code or the database.

The database connection details, which include the host, are written to the settings.php file during installation, and can be found in there.

If you're debugging a connection to an unexpected database, make sure you check all the files that are included from settings.php, as they can contain overrides of the original `$databases` array.